# AJAX creates 15 queries in db

Tags: primefaces

I have a simple datatable with cell editing in primefaces. It works, but, first, does not create JavaScript message, second, it creates 15 identically queries to db. (i can see that in hibernate console)
Code is token from official site:

```
<h:form id="form">

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

    <p:contextMenu for="clients" widgetVar="cMenu">
        <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="ui-icon-search" onclick="clientsTable.showCellEditor();return false;"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Hide Menu" icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="cMenu.hide()"/>
    </p:contextMenu>

    <p:dataTable id="clients" var="client" value="#{clientsBean.clients}" paginator="true" rows="5"
                 editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="clientsTable">

        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{clientsBean.onCellEdit}" update=":form:messages"/>

        <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:25%">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{client.name}"/></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="nameInput" value="#{client.name}"
                                                   style="width:96%"/></f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
```

So, when i edit some info and press Enter, it creates 15 queries and does not show JS message.

Bean's getClients() is a simple hibernate query (works fine), and onCellEdit() looks like

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {  
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();  
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();  

    if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  
}
```

Also new strange bug apperead : oldValue and newValue in that bean are always same.

Comment: What does your backing bean clientsBean look like?

Comment: One method getClients that executes hibernate query getAll.
Another one is copied from primefaces, in edited first post.
Also new strange bug apperead : oldValue and newValue in that bean are always same.

Comment: Is your Bean Viewscoped?